# How to use Sonatype Nexus as a mirror for Ivy dependencies

Tags: maven, ivy, nexus

Id like to use Sonatype Nexus as a company-internal maven/ivy repository. My goal is that every request goes to nexus, and if nexus does not (yet) contain the requested artifact, it should delegate the request to the official maven repository. All artifacts that were downloaded from the official maven repository should be saved on nexus (as a backup). In addition, I want to be able to save my own artifacts the server for other project to use them (e.g. internal libraries)

In a past project, we have set up a Sonatype Nexus server to be used as a mirror for the maven repository which worked fine. Now I'm struggeling with an project which uses Ivy to accomplish the same with the existing nexus installation.

In the maven project, we had the following in settings.xml

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    <interactiveMode />
    <usePluginRegistry />
    <offline />
    <pluginGroups />
    <servers>
  <server>
    <id>deployment</id>
    <username>[USERNAME]</username>
    <password>[PASSWORD]</password>
  </server>
</servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://mavenserver:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <!--make the profile active all the time -->
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

How can I accomplish the same with Ivy?

Comment: @mark-oconnor: This is absolutely not an "exact duplicate of an existing question", at least not the one you specified it as a duplicate of. This one is referring to using Nexus to proxy Ivy repositories with Maven, your reference is for using Ivy with Ant.

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are using Ivy to access Maven repositories and not some custom defined Ivy format you can use the approach [documented in the Nexus Repository Manager documentation](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ant-ivy.html).

Also check out the [examples project for a working example](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples).

And if you are using Ant you can also use Eclipse Aether instead of Ivy. More to that also in the docs and examples.